# Quel est l'équivalent français du proverbe anglais "He that will not when he may, when he will he shall have nay" ?

Tags: traduction, proverbes

Dans la langue anglaise, le proverbe :

> He that will not when he may, when he will he shall have nay

veut dire qu'il ne faut pas qu'on soit pointilleux dans nos choix.

Je cherche un équivalent français pour accompagner la morale de *Le Héron* par La Fontaine et je trouve celui-là convenable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Prendre le train quand il passe

would match this, as you can't take the train after. It can also be found as the more conventional:

> Saisir l'occasion quand elle se présente

Comment: Is there a more formal variant of this?

Comment: La fable me semble bien: on risque de tout perdre à vouloir trop gagner, gardez vous de ne rien dédaigner... What do you mean by *more formal* ? On risque de tout perdre quand on est trop exigeant (gourmand)? Il ne faut pas avoir les yeux plus grands que le ventre ?

Comment: @jcm69 "Avoir les yeux plus gros que le ventre" j'y ai pensé mais ca n'a pas vraiment le même sens (comme mieux vaut un tiens que deux tu l'auras). Mais la formulation de la fable me semble très bien, j'ai cherché une expression plus courte.